# Split words in Java with java.util.regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a text like that:

> The C language is%y% widely used today in application, operating
>   system, and embedded system development, and its influence is seen in
>   most modern programming languages. UNIX has also been influential,
>   establishing %y% concepts and principles that are now precepts of
>   computing.%p%

Text has some unnecessary indicators: %y% and %p%

I use regex for split words using this regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+");
```

I could split all words but this regex brings "y" and "p" letters. How can i ignore these indicators?

Comment: Can you post a string and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some pre-processing to remove all of the unneccesary characters before you do your main processing. Something like this should work:

```
string.replaceAll("%y%|%p%","")
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you may treat the indicators as separate words, and sort them out later:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+|%[a-z]%");
```

BTW, you should not use `[a-zA-Z]` for natural language texts - even english text could contain words like `café`, names like Björn etc. For this, java.util.regex.Pattern supports predefined character classes for letters `\p{L}` along with `\p{Ll}` (only lowercase letters) and `\p{Lu}` (only uppercase letters) that would match such words just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the only characters are "%y%" and "%p%" you could make it simple and just remove these before doing the regex..

e.g.

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("%y%|%p%", "");
```